# Linux Fork functionality in a loop

Tags: c, linux, unix

Can anyone please explain how this C code works? How many processes will be spawned after its completion?

```
int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=42; i++) 
    {
         fork();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many do you think get created?

Answer (score 3):

At each iteration of the `for` loop, `fork` is called exactly once. For each call of `fork` a new process is created; how many processes are spawned at the end depends on the length of the loop.

If the loop had length 1, only one new process would be created, for a total of 2 processes.

If the loop had length 2, at the first iteration a new process would be created; each process would then spawn another one at the next iteration, for a total of 3 calls to `fork` and 4 total processes.

As you might suppose, at each iteration the number of processes doubles; if `n` is the length of the loop, we're saying that the total number of processes would be `f(n) = 2^n` (with `2^n - 1` processes spawned). Let's prove it's true by induction. We have already seen that the formula holds for `n=1` and `n=2`. Let's suppose it's valid for `n` and prove it for `n+1`.

If the lenght is `n+1`, at the first iteration a new process is spawned, for a total of 2 processes each still having `n` iterations to do, which means (by inductive assumption) that each process will spawn `2^n - 1` processes, which means that a total of `2^(n+1) - 2` processes will be spawned in the last `n` iterations; we already had 2 processes, which means that the total created processes (counting the main one) would be `2^(n+1) - 2 + 2 = 2^(n+1)`.

In conclusion, for a loop of lenght `n` we have `2^n - 1` calls to `fork`, which means that in your case we have `2^42 - 1` new processes spawned by the main one and its descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Use this program to get the answer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    float sum=0;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=42;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + pow(2,i);
        printf("fork call:%d, processes:%1.f\n",i,sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
//When fork call is 42 the processes will be 8796093022208
```

Comment: Do the Child process also call the fork statement when it get spawned.? As we know that child process gets the complete copy of parent. So while getting a copy of parent the child process will get the fork statement. Do Child process call this fork statement?

Comment: Yes child process will also call the fork statement.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2^42, half of what you wrote?